# Azure IoT Hub - create policy with supplied keys

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-iot-hub

I'm looking for a way to create access policy in Azure IoT hub but I'd like to supply my own keys.

I can see there is a command in Azure CLI:

```
az iot hub policy create --hub-name
                         --name
                         --permissions
                         [--resource-group]
                         [--subscription]
```

but it does not allow to provide my own keys.

I couldn't find anything interesting on PowerShell as well - seems like there is no command for creating shared access policy at all using PowerShell.

There is a way to use ARM template (seems like it is possible to provide primary and secondary key (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devices/iothubs?tabs=json#iothubproperties):

```json
...
 "properties": {
    "allowedFqdnList": [ "string" ],
    "authorizationPolicies": [
      {
        "keyName": "string",
        "primaryKey": "string",
        "rights": "string",
        "secondaryKey": "string"        
      }
    ],
...
```

but it brings some hassle in terms how to provide the keys and I'm looking for something simple and preety much one-timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below sample arm template which create a basic iot hub & a shared access policy with our own keys. You need to create two files `parameters.json` & `template.json`.

- `template.json` file contains the code which resources are going to deploy.
- `parameters.json` file contains the value of those parameters that you have used in the `template.json`.

**Template.json file:**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "IotHubs_IotHub_connectionString": {
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "IotHubs_IotHub_containerName": {
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "IotHubs_IotHub_name": {
            "defaultValue": "vedodIotHub",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "IotHubs_Key_Name" : {
            "defaultValue" : "newkeyname",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "IotHubs_Key_Primary_value" : {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "IotHubs_Key_Secondary_value":{
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs",
            "apiVersion": "2021-07-02",
            "name": "[parameters('IotHubs_IotHub_name')]",
            "location": "eastus",
            "sku": {
                "name": "S1",
                "tier": "Standard",
                "capacity": 2
            },
            "identity": {
                "type": "None"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ipFilterRules": [],
                "authorizationPolicies": [
                {
                    "keyName": "[parameters('IotHubs_Key_Name')]",
                    "primaryKey": "[parameters('IotHubs_Key_Primary_value')]",
                    "secondaryKey" : "[parameters('IotHubs_Key_Secondary_value')]",
                    "rights": "RegistryRead, RegistryWrite, DeviceConnect"

                }
                ],
                "eventHubEndpoints": {
                    "events": {
                        "retentionTimeInDays": 1,
                        "partitionCount": 4
                    }
                },
                "routing": {
                    "endpoints": {
                        "serviceBusQueues": [],
                        "serviceBusTopics": [],
                        "eventHubs": [],
                        "storageContainers": []
                    },
                    "routes": [],
                    "fallbackRoute": {
                        "name": "$fallback",
                        "source": "DeviceMessages",
                        "condition": "true",
                        "endpointNames": [
                            "events"
                        ],
                        "isEnabled": true
                    }
                },
                "storageEndpoints": {
                    "$default": {
                        "sasTtlAsIso8601": "PT1H",
                        "connectionString": "[parameters('IotHubs_IotHub_connectionString')]",
                        "containerName": "[parameters('IotHubs_IotHub_containerName')]"
                    }
                },
                "messagingEndpoints": {
                    "fileNotifications": {
                        "lockDurationAsIso8601": "PT1M",
                        "ttlAsIso8601": "PT1H",
                        "maxDeliveryCount": 10
                    }
                },
                "enableFileUploadNotifications": false,
                "cloudToDevice": {
                    "maxDeliveryCount": 10,
                    "defaultTtlAsIso8601": "PT1H",
                    "feedback": {
                        "lockDurationAsIso8601": "PT1M",
                        "ttlAsIso8601": "PT1H",
                        "maxDeliveryCount": 10
                    }
                },
                "features": "None"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**parameters.json file :**

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "IotHubs_IotHub_connectionString": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "IotHubs_IotHub_containerName": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "IotHubs_IotHub_name": {
            "value": "<IotHubName>"
        },
        "IotHubs_Key_Name":{
            "value" : "<sharedaccesspolicyKeyName>"
        },
        "IotHubs_Key_Primary_value": {
            "value" : "<accesspolicyPrimaryKeyValue>"
        },
        "IotHubs_Key_Secondary_value":{
            "value" : "<accesspolicySecondaryKeyValue>" 
        }
    }
}
```

Using the below Powershell cmdlets to deploy the create a Iot hub & passing the above template.json & parameters.json file as parameters :

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroupName> -TemplateFile '<pathfortemplate.jsonfile>' -TemplateParameterFile '<Pathforparameters.jsonfile>'
```

**Here is the sample output screenshot for reference:**

[image]